# Wordpress : Display Text While a period

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I have a question.
How can display a text while 4 days in PHP ?

Example : I wrote a post today, and I want display "New" while 4 days and hide this after that.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is NOT specific to WordPress, and you'll want to remove the `foreach` loop for actual use.. but it should give you an idea of how to compare relative dates:

```
<?php
    $sample_dates = array(
        '2011-02-17',
        '2011-02-18',
        '2011-02-19',
        '2011-02-20',
        '2011-02-21',
        '2011-02-22',
        '2011-02-23'
    );

    $post_date = '2011-02-17';

    foreach ($sample_dates as $date_today) {
        echo '<p>If today is ' . $date_today . ', the post from ' . $post_date . ' is: ';
        if (strtotime('+4 days',strtotime($post_date)) >= strtotime($date_today)) {
            echo 'NEW';
        } else {
            echo 'OLD';
        }
        echo '</p>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
?>
```